# "error with web service Android ksoap2 object reference not set to a instance of a object

Tags: android

I'm creating an app and want to send a object to a web-service and I get an error
obeject reference not set to an instance of an object. I don't know if I am sending them correctly.

I'm new in Android with ksoap.
This is what I tried:

`
public String sendPostSoap_registarContentor(String requestname ,   String soapAction) {

```
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", requestname);//nome do metodo "ObterDadosContentor"

    Registar_Entrada_Contentor obj = new Registar_Entrada_Contentor();

    obj.Tipo= Tipo;
    obj.IdContentor= IdContentor;
    obj.IdEstadoContentor= IdEstadoContentor;
    obj.IdNavio= IdNavio;
    obj.IdTipoMovimentacao= IdTipoMovimentacao;
    obj.IdTipoTrafego= IdTipoTrafego;
    obj.IdDimensaoContentor= IdDimensaoContentor;
    obj.Localizacoes= Localizacoes;
    obj.NumeroEscala=null;
    obj.NumeroListaDesembarque=null;
    obj.NumeroGuiaEntrada=null;

    PropertyInfo pro = new PropertyInfo();
    pro.setName("obj");
    pro.setValue(obj);
    pro.setType(obj.getClass());
    request.addProperty(pro);



    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.addMapping("http://tempuri.org/","obj",new Registar_Entrada_Contentor().getClass() );

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://172.16.0.36/GestaoParqueQUAL/Service/ParqueContentorService.asmx");
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    String result = null;
    String resultado = null;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope); //metodo recebe soap action e o metodo "http://tempuri.org/ObterDadosContentor"
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

          //resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        Object results = envelope.getResponse();
        result = results.toString();


        String x = null;


    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

`

I expect the output to be a json whit`retorno:true,Mensagem: ok`because the obj is populate, but the actual output of the json return ```retorno:false,Mensagem: the object reference is not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: If all fails,i suggest you try Volley or Retrofit for networking in android,they are several examples on how to use Volley for example,and you'll get help faster

Comment: thanks for the suggest  Hilary Mwape but i have make the app from the beggining with ksoap2 i have some other request that funcion. next app i will  try with volley or retrofit.

Comment: the object arrived in webservice with all null values. I solve the problem.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer,so you can help people with same problem in future

Answer (score 0):

the object arrived in webservice with all null values. I solve the problem i needet to create  a object with `implements KvmSerializable`